# sql login and redirecting users to different pages

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

NET, VB.NET and SQL SERVER 2014 for my bachelors graduate project. 
I have a 'users' table for signing in, the columns are:
 username, password and type.
and I want to create a login page which will compare the username and password that the user interned with the database and if they match it will take the user to a specific page d*epending on the value of '**type**'*.
 I've had success with a code that I found online for checking the username and password but when I tried to add to it for opening pages depending on 'type' the result is always **"invalid username and password"**

This is the original code:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconnection").ConnectionString)
    con.Open()
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from Admin_Table where UserName =@username and Password=@password", con)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPWD.Text)

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dt As New DataTable()

da.Fill(dt)
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
Response.Redirect("Details.aspx")
    Else

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.[GetType](),
                                           "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>")
    End If
End Sub */
```

and this is what I tried to do:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
Dim con As New  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconnection").ConnectionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users where username=@username and password=@password and type=@type", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPWD.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", TextBox1.Text).ToString()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 And TextBox1.Text = "doctors" Then

        Response.Redirect("Details.aspx")

    ElseIf dt.Rows.Count > 0 And TextBox1.Text = "admin" Then
        Response.Redirect("db.aspx")
    Else
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.[GetType](),
                                           "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>")
    End If
End Sub
```

the username and password I enter are correct but it displays "invalid username and password".

Comment: Never store passwords in plaintext in a database. Salt and hash them instead. Also, SQL text comparisons are case-insensitive.

Comment: Does it return any record if you query with correct credential in SSMS? For example - `SELECT * FROM users where username='johndoe' and password='1234'`

Comment: @Dai I aoplogize for not replying sooner, I will Salt and Hash the passwords thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Win I apologize for not replying sooner and thank you for trying to help I found another way to make it work and I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I thought I'd post it for other beginners who might be looking for the same code.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Partial Class bb_form_1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page



Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconnection").ConnectionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users where username=@username and password=@password", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPWD.Text)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Username and Password")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If dt.Rows(0)(2) = "admin" Then
        Response.Redirect("AddAdmin.aspx")
    ElseIf dt.Rows(0)(2) = "doctor" Then
        Response.Redirect("AddMeds.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```